Postdoc reco as PI won't even co-sign undergrads who aren't co-authors
My whole summer I worked meticulously in a REU for the PI to tell he never writes or signs letters of recommendation for interns. I need a third recommender; my first two are great profs.
Will the postdoc who mentored me closely be a good option or should I take one from a professor who doesn't know me but I have taken the class. I am really frantic I can use examples of people who got in with 1/3 reco from a postdoc of a completely different lab.

A postdoc who knows you well would be a good letter of reference.
And, in general, a strong letter from someone who knows you (your research or academics) well is better than a letter from a more famous/prestigious/important person.
For example, a supervisor at a relevant job (e.g., summer internship in a relevant field), a postdoc, lab manager, or similar position would be okay,especially, if you have strong letters from professors.

+1. I would just add that if the post-doc can write in their letter that the prof has a firm policy of never writing LoRs for interns, that would probably be a good idea.

@cag51, indeed, although "protesting too much" would not be good. Simply something succinct, like "By the way, Prof X has a firm policy of not writing letters for interns, so I'm writing the relevant letter for Y."

This is a good idea I will let him know
